# Exception against Oracle DB: "Error while determining database product name: Unsupported feature"

Tags: oracle, jdbc, flyway

I am attempting to use Flyway 2.0.3 against the following Oracle database:

- **Oracle Database:** Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.5.0
- **Oracle JDBC Driver:** v9.0.2.0.0

When trying to use Flyway through maven (mvn flyway:info -e), I get the error below:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Unsupported feature
    at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:134)
    at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:179)
    at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:269)
    at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwUnsupportedFeatureSqlException(DBError.java:689)
    at oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseMetaData.getDatabaseMajorVersion(OracleDatabaseMetaData.java:4442)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.dbsupport.DbSupportFactory.getDatabaseProductName(DbSupportFactory.java:113)
    ... 27 more
```

Although if I try again, but using newer versions of the driver (v9.2+), flyway works fine :)

Looking at the offending OracleDatabaseMetaData.getDatabaseMajorVersion() method, I can see that it throws the explicitly throws the 'Unsupported feature' SQLException.

I was wondering if there is a reason why flyway may not cater for this eventuality?

Could it be an oversight (I can look into submitting a patch) or is it that Flyway can only support certain versions of the oracle driver (for whatever reason, not critiquing).

Cheers Guys!!!

**UPDATE: Workaround**

As I am using maven, I defined a newer version of the oracle driver in the flyway plugin definition. The project can still use the old driver dependency and the plugin can use a newer version:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    ...
</dependencies>

<plugin>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.flyway</groupId>
    <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
            <version>10.2.0.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
                ...
    </dependencies>
        ...
</plugin>
```

Comment: Why don't you use a current driver for 10.x? You shouldn't be using a 9.x driver agains a 10.x database anyway.

Comment: According to [this](http://flywaydb.org/documentation/database/oracle.html) Flyway only supports database version 10g and later. I'm not sure you'll get much sympathy from them for using a driver from an older release, even though [Oracle allow it](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-faq-090281.html#02_02). (I was going to suggest asking on their support forums, but [I see that you have](http://flywaydb.org/support/)!)

Comment: Like Alex mentioned, Oracle 10g is supported by the v9.X drivers. 

I could upgrade the driver, but that would require a large amount of regression testing. It's been added to the list of things we need to upgrade next time we do a tech upgrade.

A fix for me, is to define a newer version of the oracle driver, as a dependency directly in the plugin in my maven pom. More info in the post below, for those who need it.

Comment: In my experience the 9.x drivers were full of bugs. The 10.x drivers were much better (and much faster in some areas). I wouldn't use anything but the 11.x drivers nowadays unless someone held a gun to my head.