# org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Error while determining database product name

Tags: flyway

below is my JNDI lookup for the Datasource

```
<bean id="datasource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/intdb" />
</bean>
```

and flyway bean config is

```
<bean id="flyway" class="org.flywaydb.core.Flyway" init-method="migrate">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="datasource" />
    </bean>
```

i am getting below exception, but if i replace JNDI lookup with all the properties in the bean it works fine,

> Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Error while
>   determining database product name
>         at org.flywaydb.core.internal.dbsupport.DbSupportFactory.getDatabaseProductName(DbSupportFactory.java:139)
>         at org.flywaydb.core.internal.dbsupport.DbSupportFactory.createDbSupport(DbSupportFactory.java:59)
>         at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.execute(Flyway.java:1147)
>         at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:811)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1581)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1522)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
>         ... 26 more
>       Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Unsupported feature
>         at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:134)
>         at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:179)
>         at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:269)
>         at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwUnsupportedFeatureSqlException(DBError.java:689)
>         at oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseMetaData.getDatabaseMajorVersion(OracleDatabaseMetaData.java:4442)
>         at org.flywaydb.core.internal.dbsupport.DbSupportFactory.getDatabaseProductName(DbSupportFactory.java:134)

Answer (score 1):

I have got similar, **working** configuration in my project. In spring context XML I have got:

```html
<bean id="migrationDataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
  <property name="jndiName" value="jdbc/myTestDb"/>
</bean>
<bean id="dbMigrationManager" class="test.version.DbMigrationManager" init-method="updateDatabaseSchema">
  <constructor-arg name="migrationDataSource" ref="migrationDataSource"/>
</bean>
```

I am wrapping data source by constructor argument in DbMigrationManager. It looks like this:

package test.version;

```java
import org.flywaydb.core.Flyway;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

public class DbMigrationManager {

  private final DataSource dataSource;

  public DbMigrationManager(DataSource migrationDataSource) {
      this.dataSource = migrationDataSource;
  }

  public void updateDatabaseSchema() {
      Flyway flyway = new Flyway();
      flyway.setDataSource(dataSource);
      flyway.migrate();
  }

}
```

Also I am using Flyway 3.0 version in gradle like this:

```java
compile group: 'org.flywaydb', name: 'flyway-core', version: '3.0'
```

If that do not help then maybe your problem is database specific. Like in this thread:

[Exception against Oracle DB: "Error while determining database product name: Unsupported feature"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14734804/exception-against-oracle-db-error-while-determining-database-product-name-uns)

Or you are using some older, buggy version of Flyway.